# Android webview won't load my URL but will load others

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webiew app on android which loads some websites but not the one I need it to.

I have no idea if this is a problem with the website host or something I can do in my app. Basically I have an online portfolio I'm making for university and I want to make myself look better by building it into an app. The portfolio site includes a mobile version so it's already set up for that and works fine in the chrome browser on my phone.

It used to work with an old site and it loads google so I know I have the internet permission right. Not sure if it's something to do with my new site or I just need to change something to make it work.

In the chrome browser it looks as it should, which isn't good at the moment because I wanted to do this first before I added content to it. [This is how it looks.](https://s29.postimg.cc/at6fjc5yf/image.png) (Can't post a screenshot directly as I don't have enough rep, sorry)

Here is my main app code:

```
package com.broadbentstudios;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class ParseStarterProjectActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.broadbentstudios.com/");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }                
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView!=null && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }        
    {
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
    }       
}
```

Screenshot of my site when using my app [with the code above.](https://s3.postimg.cc/f6h172d77/image.png)

Here is the **logcat**.

```
04-12 18:51:45.686: D/PowerManagerService(1196): acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=903227323, flags=0x1, tag="LocationManagerService", ws=WorkSource{1000 com.qualcomm.location}, uid=1000, pid=1196
04-12 18:51:45.686: D/PowerManagerService(1196): acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=662236910, flags=0x1, tag="LocationManagerService", ws=WorkSource{10013 com.google.android.gms}, uid=1000, pid=1196
04-12 18:51:45.687: D/PowerManagerService(1196): acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=531027438, flags=0x1, tag="LocationManagerService", ws=WorkSource{10013 com.google.android.gms}, uid=1000, pid=1196
04-12 18:51:45.687: D/PowerManagerService(1196): releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=959227632 [LocationManagerService], flags=0x0
04-12 18:51:45.687: D/PowerManagerService(1196): releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=546372682 [LocationManagerService], flags=0x0
04-12 18:51:45.688: D/PowerManagerService(1196): releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=662236910 [LocationManagerService], flags=0x0
04-12 18:51:45.688: D/PowerManagerService(1196): releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=531027438 [LocationManagerService], flags=0x0
04-12 18:51:45.689: D/PowerManagerService(1196): releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=197382963 [LocationManagerService], flags=0x0
04-12 18:51:45.689: D/PowerManagerService(1196): releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=903227323 [LocationManagerService], flags=0x0
04-12 18:51:45.734: I/LibraryLoader(28664): Time to load native libraries: 34 ms (timestamps 2209-2243)
04-12 18:51:45.734: I/LibraryLoader(28664): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
04-12 18:51:45.747: V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider(28664): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {24dd5d0b}
04-12 18:51:45.747: I/LibraryLoader(28664): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
04-12 18:51:45.747: I/chromium(28664): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(108)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
04-12 18:51:45.757: I/BrowserStartupController(28664): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
04-12 18:51:45.758: W/art(28664): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
04-12 18:51:45.768: W/AudioManagerAndroid(28664): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
04-12 18:51:45.769: W/chromium(28664): [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(304)] locale_file_path.empty()
04-12 18:51:45.770: I/chromium(28664): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(63)] Load from apk succesful, fd=59 off=45928 len=3221
04-12 18:51:45.770: I/chromium(28664): [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(76)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:60 off:390788 len:1143511
04-12 18:51:45.775: D/libEGL(28664): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
04-12 18:51:45.776: D/libEGL(28664): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
04-12 18:51:45.788: D/libEGL(28664): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
04-12 18:51:45.803: I/Adreno-EGL(28664): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1.C2.05.00.00.046.002_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.1.C2__release_AU ()
04-12 18:51:45.803: I/Adreno-EGL(28664): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
04-12 18:51:45.803: I/Adreno-EGL(28664): Build Date: 01/06/15 Tue
04-12 18:51:45.803: I/Adreno-EGL(28664): Local Branch: mybranch6793908
04-12 18:51:45.803: I/Adreno-EGL(28664): Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1.c2
04-12 18:51:45.803: I/Adreno-EGL(28664): Local Patches: NONE
04-12 18:51:45.803: I/Adreno-EGL(28664): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1.C2.05.00.00.046.002 +  NOTHING
04-12 18:51:45.868: W/chromium(28664): [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(328)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
04-12 18:51:45.890: W/art(28664): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
04-12 18:51:45.895: W/AwContents(28664): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
04-12 18:51:45.917: E/QCOMSysDaemon(28750): Can't open /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/bootselect: (No such file or directory)
04-12 18:51:45.917: I/QCOMSysDaemon(28750): Starting qcom system daemon
04-12 18:51:45.917: E/Diag_Lib(28750):  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
04-12 18:51:45.917: E/QCOMSysDaemon(28750):  Diag_LSM_Init failed : 0
04-12 18:51:45.953: D/OpenGLRenderer(28664): Render dirty regions requested: true
04-12 18:51:45.956: D/Atlas(28664): Validating map...
04-12 18:51:45.962: E/com.parse.push(28664): successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.
04-12 18:51:45.963: D/PowerManagerService(1196): acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=553909931, flags=0x1, tag="Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION flg=0x10 pkg=com.broadbentstudios cmp=com.broadbentstudios/com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver (has extras) }", ws=null, uid=10221, pid=28664
04-12 18:51:45.992: I/OpenGLRenderer(28664): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-12 18:51:45.997: D/OpenGLRenderer(28664): Enabling debug mode 0
04-12 18:51:46.009: D/PowerManagerService(1196): releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=553909931 [Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION flg=0x10 pkg=com.broadbentstudios cmp=com.broadbentstudios/com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver (has extras) }], flags=0x0
04-12 18:51:46.029: I/Timeline(28664): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@19326283 time:33412539
04-12 18:51:46.030: D/PowerManagerService(1196): releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=110279535 [ActivityManager-Launch], flags=0x0
04-12 18:51:46.038: I/ActivityManager(1196): Displayed com.broadbentstudios/.ParseStarterProjectActivity: +864ms
04-12 18:51:46.038: I/Timeline(1196): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{3eff1853 u0 com.broadbentstudios/.ParseStarterProjectActivity t1645} time:33412548
04-12 18:51:46.055: D/ForegroundUtils(4725): Foreground changed, PID: 4813 UID: 10182 foreground: false
04-12 18:51:46.055: D/ForegroundUtils(4725): Foreground UID/PID combinations:
04-12 18:51:46.055: D/ForegroundUtils(4725): UID: 10221 PID: 28664
04-12 18:51:46.386: D/AbstractMetricsFactoryImpl(28721): record : No data points in metrics event
04-12 18:51:46.637: W/BindingManager(28664): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 28664
04-12 18:51:47.134: I/chromium(28664): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "'webkitIDBRequest' is deprecated. Please use 'IDBRequest' instead.", source:  (0)
04-12 18:51:47.422: I/chromium(28664): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "HARD RESET!!", source: http://www.broadbentstudios.com/application/_output/pb.out.front.js?v=7 (1)
04-12 18:51:47.440: I/chromium(28664): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clear' of null", source: http://www.broadbentstudios.com/application/_output/pb.out.front.js?v=7 (1)
04-12 18:51:48.338: D/audio_hw_primary(253): out_standby: enter: stream (0xb5801780) usecase(1: low-latency-playback)
```

Any help would be great, even if it's just so I know if it's my app or the site that is causing the problems.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Finally found the answer after a lot of searching. For anybody in a similar situation, as well as enabling javascript you also need to enable Dom storage by adding in;

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Change webView to whatever yours is called and you should be good to go.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: You sir, made my day :) Thx

Comment: @luQ Glad I could help, it took me days to find this so I know the pain haha.

Comment: @LewisBroadbent Thanks man.... you are a good developer....as you understand other developers pain...appreciated!!!

Comment: @AndroidKiller Thanks :) I definitely understand the pain haha.

Answer (score 0):

Your website has a JavaScript error. Did you try something about that error in the log you shared?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clear' of null", source:
>   http://www.broadbentstudios.com/application/_output/pb.out.front.js?v=7
>   (1)

Comment: I tried disbaling javascript as a longshot but that didn't help and I didn't think it would. I'm also a huge noob at this so I'm not really sure what else to try, I've looked around on the internet but people were just saying to add the internet permission which I already had. Is there anything you can suggest for me try? Thanks for pointing that out for me, I'm mostly new to logcat too and guess I missed it.

Comment: Disabling JavaScript wouldn't work because your page is probably using it to load its content. You need to figure out what is causing the JavaScript error. Also, are you testing on an emulator or on your device? I can load http://www.broadbentstudios.com/ on my Chrome app running Android 5.0.1 which means the WebView of any app should be able to open it at least on Android 5.

Comment: Yeah I thought it was but I gave it a go anyway. That's the confusing thing, I'm running it on my actual phone which is 5.0.2 and it works fine in my chrome app.

Answer (score 0):

I recently create one repository with a basic web view application for android with some error handling for no internet connection

https://github.com/jgarciabt/SmartWebView

You can clone it and start your application from it, maybe that is easier.

Comment: I am writing some documentation about how it works so if you are not in a rush you can check it later also =)

Comment: Thanks, I might need that I just tried to install and run it with my web address in it and it just says Unfortunately, SmartWebView has stopped and I get a lot of errors in the logcat haha

Comment: Can you send me the log by email please? I am still debugging it. jgarciabt@gmail.com Thank you

Comment: Done :) I looked to see if I could send it to you on here, but I couldn't see any way to. Hope it helps with he debugging, not sure if it'll help but I'm running 5.0.2 on a OneplusOne.