# Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid - Not navigate to the Html page

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

Below is my code to open the home.html page upon successful login for my Android app. But when I click the login button it loads the same index.html page (It isn't opening `home.html`).

```
function check(form)  {
    //the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching
    if(form.password.value == "moleac123") {
        if(form.remember_me.checked) {
            window.localStorage["password_remember"] = "moleac123";
            var date_to_remember = new Date().getTime();
            window.localStorage["date_remember"] = date_to_remember.toString();
        }
        $.mobile.pageLoadErrorMessage = "";
       // window.open('home.html'); //opens the target page while Id & password matches
       window.location="home.html";
    }
    else {
        alert("Invalid Password"); //displays error message
        $.mobile.pageLoadErrorMessage = "";
       // window.open('index.html');
        window.location="index.html";
    }
  }
```

I got the below error on my logcat. (Note my query mobile version is 1.3.2 and I have tried to upgrade to 1.4.5 still the same issue occurs)

```
Error:

D/JsMessageQueue﹕ Set native->JS mode to null D/CordovaWebViewImpl﹕ onPageDidNavigate(file:///android_asset/www/home.html)

W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 20994

D/CordovaWebViewImpl﹕ onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/home.html)

W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 20994

W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 20994
```

Note- This works fine in Android 4.1.X version, it has this issue in Android5.0

Please advice how I could fix this.

Comment: Are you got solution ?

Comment: [Android Webview: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33083066/6521116)

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29978620/4070848)?  In the logcat for that post there is something about `BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility()` so maybe the suggested solution will help here too?