# Android Webview: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid

Tags: java, android, file, webview, download

I have a Android Webview and when I click on a link to download a file (image of pdf etc) I got a error message.

```
Error message:
Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid
```

Any idea what I do wrong? Who can help please!?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just a bit of configuration:

```
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I got the same problem and this lines did not solve my problem.

Comment: How did you solve your problem @marceloquinta? Mine isn't working with this either.

Comment: this is also gives same warning for me? any other solutions??

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error and Burhans solution was not helping me.
I think things went wrong when you´re trying to load different urls too fast.

Edit: Found a better solution credits go to user2652394 
[WebView must be loaded twice to load correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112715/webview-must-be-loaded-twice-to-load-correctly/18117196#18117196)

You have to do something like this:

```
        webView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                webView.loadUrl(landingpage);
            }
        }, 500);
```

Comment: fixed, but by calling inside `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue.

Was solved by giving a WebView a static height (ie 300dp) or specifying minHeight value.

Answer (score 2):

This problem in my case produce by incorrect settings in layout properties. I had used:

```
    <WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false" />
```

Instead of setting:

```
    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />
```

The problems had been solved, when I removed "layout_alignParent" settings.

Comment: Great! All the other solutions did not work for me. This one worked :)

Answer (score 2):

## Background

Here is the source code of the **method** in the *browser engine* that gives the **error** (**BindingManagerImpl.java**), from [Chromium source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/experimental/chromium/src/+/refs/wip/bajones/webvr/content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/content/browser/BindingManagerImpl.java):

```
@Override
public void determinedVisibility(int pid) {
    ManagedConnection managedConnection;
    synchronized (mManagedConnections) {
        managedConnection = mManagedConnections.get(pid);
    }
    if (managedConnection == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: "
                + "%d", pid);
        return;
    }
```

## Analysis

It's a ***rendering warning*** from content.

**Consecutive** calls to `loadUrl` cause a **race condition**. The problem is that `loadUrl("file://..")` **doesn't** complete immediately, and so when you call `loadUrl("javascript:..")` it will sometimes execute ***before***
 the page has loaded.

## Detail

For more detail see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227252/could-someone-once-and-for-all-please-explain-cannot-call-determinedvisibility/40477924#40477924) stackoverflow answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed a similar issue:

```
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    mWebView.loadURL(...
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to party, but might help some.
May sound silly as hell, but the mistake I made was not adding `http://` in the beginning of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether internet permission is properly set on the Manifest file. Make sure that **the permission tag should be outside** of your Application tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Hope this might help some one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by using `onPageFinished` method instead of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. It also provides the needed URL in the list of arguments.

The only trick is to set a check so that the main logic of the method (in my case making a Toast) is not triggered when `onPageFinished` gets called on the the page load itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, 
    String mimetype, long contentLength) {
    Log.d("download",url);
  }
});
```

Comment: A helpful answer should always explain why the problem (error) is occurring as well as explaining why the suggested answer (your code) should work or fix it. Without any explanation this answer is not helpful - this is very important especially for a question that already has a number of answers submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I can fix my issue by giving this code:

```
webView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }, 500);
```

instead of:

```
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

then, set the `url` starts with  `https://`