# Ti.UI.WebView on Android: webpage is not being displayed

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am using a WebView in my app. This WebView must display an external webpage. It works fine on iOS, but on Android I get a white screen.

In the console I see this warning:
W/cr.BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid

I added debug messages inside the load event of the WebView. When I call the getHtml method there I see that the html is being retrieved. 
I have no idea why it is not being displayed?

I find some similar issues on stackoverflow (issues that were not related with Titanium) but this issues did not point me to a solution.
Here is one of the issues I've found:

[Android Webview: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083066/android-webview-cannot-call-determinedvisibility-never-saw-a-connection-for)

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: put webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

Comment: It would be helpful if you can paste some code here

Comment: @Viren: The Titanium WebView does not have a getSettings method so I cannot implement your suggestion. Thanks anyway.

Comment: the code is very simple:

var wv =Ti.UI.createWebView();
wv.setUserAgent('myCustomUserAgent');
wv.setUrl("https://www.myurl.com");

Comment: it looks there is no error in your code ....the problem is with your URL. Try wv.setUrl("http://www.google.com");

Comment: @Suraj. Yes I can agree with that. Something inside the webpage that I want to display causes this. If I change the Url to a different one. it's working. The thing is, when I open the page in a browser (Chrome) it's being displayed good. I also checked for javascript errors (in the console), no errors. So I have no idea why the website is not being displayed inside my WebView. 

I hope I can find someone with similar problems (and a solution for it)

Comment: @StefanH Can you paste the url here ?

Comment: @Suraj, I've sent you a connect request via LinkedIn and I can share the URL there. The website can only be retrieved with a custom user agent so beside the url I have to give you the user agent string. I cannot share that string on stack overflow so I sent you a private message. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @Surajkochale found someone with similar issues. Do you have found a fix or workaround yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have solved the problem for

> BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a
>   connection for the pid

and for

> libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

by using the following WebView for android: http://gitt.io/component/de.marcelpociot.webviewfragment , which contains fixes for : https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIDOC-1548

Answer (score 1):

Try adding borderRadius: 1 to the Webview properties

> var webview = Ti.UI.createWebView({url: '..', borderRadius: 1});

This disabled the hardware acceleration of the webview..

See the docs for more information: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView

Comment: I already tried that without success. Some other errors occur when I add a borderRadius:
[ERROR] :  SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
[ERROR] :  chromium: [ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(258)] Failed to init browser shader disk cache.
[WARN] :   W/cr.media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
[ERROR] :  libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

Comment: We have exactly the same issue.   libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
[INFO] :   Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@f73b081 time:51159278
[WARN] :   cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 29233

Comment: This solved my problem with my project. Thanks for your simple, useful, and grate trick!