# Appcelerator Webview doesnt show my site on Android

Tags: android, css, webview, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have a project that simply displays a website. My code is:

```
function pencere() {
    var self = Ti.UI.createView({ width:"100%", height:"100%" });
    
    var webPencere = Ti.UI.createWebView({ left:1, right:1,  top:1, bottom:1, url:"http://www.radyobasaksehir.com" });

    self.add(webPencere);

    return self;
}
```

My friend told me that the Android browser doesn't support the new CSS and HTML codes. I don't know the exact meaning of these but I think I need to revise my code but I couldn't figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to chromium WebView being used Android 4.4.

There is developed a module for solving this. But, I found advice [here in another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34944007/ti-ui-webview-on-android-webpage-is-not-being-displayed)

Just add **borderRadius** property with a minimum value. Sample code:

```
var webview = Ti.UI.createWebView({url: '..', borderRadius: 1});
```