# why cant i download file in android webview via POST

Tags: android, http, webview

I want to download the file using `Webview` in Android, but sometimes it doesn't work.

For example, if we have a webpage and this page have a `form`, when we submit this form some file will be download.If you set the form submit method to `get` webview will call `onDownloadStart()` method to download file,but if you set the form submit method to `post` ,webview will never call `onDownloadStart()` method,at the same time `logcat` print this warning.

> Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid:

*Can't download:*

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="/download">
    <input type="hidden" id="fileName" name="fileName" value="Test.doc"/>
</form>
```

*Can download:*

```
<form id="form" method="get" action="/download">
    <input type="hidden" id="fileName" name="fileName" value="Test.doc"/>
</form>
```

And also i did a test in different Android Version: Android 7.0 and Android 2.X，only Android 2.X can work correctly.

**Can you help me solve this problem or give me a hint?**

Comment: Can you confirm that your server does actually support `POST`ing to `\download` URI?

Comment: yes it's  actually support

Comment: Then, if your logcat message is indeed the problem, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083066/android-webview-cannot-call-determinedvisibility-never-saw-a-connection-for)