# Android: How to display Youtube Channel in a webview activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, webview, youtube

Hello fellow programmers. Some background info, I'm quite new to android app development and decided to work on a personal project to practice my hand at it. In working on the project, most problems I encountered, I could overcome them through various Google searches. However this one issue has remained evident for quite a while now.

I want to display a YouTube channel in a webview. I've studied the other related forums but have found no working solution. If you want a working example of this, check out the "Markiplier Unofficial App", that makes use of a webview to display and play his YouTube videos. Below is the code I've so far for this activity.

The Webview layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:id="@+id/userOptionsLinearLayout"
   android:background="#000000">

   <WebView
      android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Custom WebViewClient:

```
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AJSYTWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
String site_url_one = "www.youtube.com";
String site_url_two = "m.youtube.com";

// Used to judge which URL to keep open in app and which ones to divert to web browser or another app.
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().startsWith(site_url_one) || Uri.parse(url).getHost().startsWith(site_url_two)) {
        return false; // Ensures URL opens in app
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    return true;
 }
}
```

The WebView Activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class ajs_youtube_page extends AppCompatActivity {

   // Declaring Programming Webview variable.
   private WebView mwebView;

   // Primary URL.
   String url = "www.youtube.com/user/AngryJoeShow";

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_ajs_youtube_page);

     // Finding webview on layout screen.
     mwebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
     //mwebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

     // Getting and adjusting WebView settings for javascript functionality.
     WebSettings webSettings = mwebView.getSettings();
     webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     //webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

     // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
     mwebView.setWebViewClient(new AJSYTWebViewClient());

     mwebView.loadUrl(url);
}

// When the back button is pressed, it goes back to the previous screen.
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mwebView.canGoBack()) {
        mwebView.goBack();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
 }
}
```

Any guidance on this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so after reading through everyone's answers/suggestions and trying them out, unfortunately they did not work. Going on yet another research spree I finally found a solution. Please keep in mind that this isn't the best method performance wise, but for a new learner like me it works.

You need to add the following code into the activity calling your webview layout:

```
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

I hope this helps someone. Below will be the link/URL to the question I found this answer at (surprised it evaded my eye all this time): [Android webview won't load my URL but will load others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592695/android-webview-wont-load-my-url-but-will-load-others)

Thanks to all those who responded. Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

Change your URL from www.youtube.com to https://www.youtube.com/

Comment: Hey UserKh, I had tried that long before posting on here. I tried different variations of the URL, all of them resulted in failure sadly.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. If you're interested, please check my answer to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like below:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().startsWith(site_url_one) || Uri.parse(url).getHost().startsWith(site_url_two)) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true; // Ensures URL opens in app
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code above makes no difference as I still get a blank page. To make sure that it's not just YouTube, I tried google.com as well, but I still get the same result. Strangely enough this works for Facebook and Twitter. Any other ideas?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. If you're interested, please check my answer to the question. Thanks.